# How to like a Facebook page through xcode?

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to like a page on Facebook (for example https://www.facebook.com/pages/iPhone/109336685751749?fref=ts).

This is the iPhone page on Facebook.

How can I do it through xCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download sample from here: https://github.com/brow/FacebookLikeView

And then add in your app. It will like your link when you made small changes in main class of sample.